# Do cameras in blender give an accurate representation of a shot as if it were shot with a real camera in live-action?

Tags: camera

Hello Blender Community,

I am prepping a live-action film shoot taking place in a swimming pool.

I have built a 3d replica of the location in Blender in order to be able to place my cameras in the set and find the shots I need ahead of the shoot.

My question is, does the field of view/ focal length in Blender match the same given focal length in reality. Aka, will the cameras in Blender give me an accurate visualisation of what the shot will look like at the live-action shoot?

I have attached a few images to give an example:
If at the live-action shoot I put my camera like in screenshot 2, will I get the same exact shot as in screenshot 1? (Providing I have built the 3d set following the correct measurements of the real location)

I hope this question is not too confusing.

Thank you for your help
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

No.

Focal length is only optics parameter, you should get the right sensor size for reconstruction. Blender has some presets for you:

[image]

You can also make a video from the camera, make 3D tracking and get a estimated field of view from it.